# Php Preg_Replace not matching quantity of characters

Tags: php, preg-replace, digits, quantifiers

I'm trying to filter a string by preg_replacing. Anything but numbers and dot and no more than 5 numbers before the dot. PHP 5.4.3 under wamp(UptoDate).

Good Matche:

- 0.01
- 0.1
- 12345.11
- 12345.1
- 1
- 12345

Bad Matchs:

- 0,10
- 0,1
- 12345,11
- 12345,1
- 123456

The first problem I have is that i can't strip the (,) comma, I only want to keep a (.)dot as separator. Keep in mind this is for a price string. Php doesn't seem to calculate with (,) comma, so i want input to be only with . and not comma. So i used (^), negates the character class, then 0-9. . Then i add the number of characters to match. I was between 1-5 (1 or 2 or 3 or... 5

What am i doing wrong.

Here is info i've been using to help:
http://www.regular-expressions.info/reference.html
http://www.expreg.com/options.php

```
<?php $string = 'asd321asd321df564d.fasd321asd12';

$string = cleanabc123($string);

function cleanabc123($data) {   $data =
preg_replace("/([^0-9\s\.]){1,5}/u", "", $data);    return $data; }

// This will be 'username' now echo $string; ?>
```

Comment: Remember that the dot is not a metacharacter inside a character class, so we do not need to escape it with a backslash.

Comment: Ah ok so this is correct: /[^0-9.\s]/. But i still don't get what i expect.

Answer (score 1):

It makes more sense to invert your intention: use preg_match() to only find a good result. Otherwise return FALSE or NULL.

This way, your regexp will be easier to write and to understand.

BTW, the way you're doing it now, you'd be better of using `preg_replace("/[^\d\.]/u", "", $str)`, replacing all incorrect characters independent of their position.

Comment: Yes you mite be right, it may be better to use preg_match but i'm not sure i could use it with an array from a html input "prices[]".

Comment: Doesn't matter, probleme solved. I just need to preg_match array entry by array entry. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I would replace

```
preg_replace("/([^0-9\s\.]){1,5}/u", "", $data);
```

with

```
$match = preg_match("/^[0-9]+([,.][0-9]{1,5})?$/u", $data);
```

I would prefer using `preg_match` in this case and I would return `$match`.

Comment: Yes thanks, this is pattern is working for me. returns array with matche(s). What are these parameters: "?$" ?

Comment: Well, the `?` says that it is an optional part. So, if your number doesn't have the `[,.][0-9]{1,5}` part it's fine. Also, the `^ ... $` operator says that the string must `^` start and `$` finish the way the expression defines.